# Odd blank screen for Mail account login after unlocking keychain

Tags: macos, gmail, apple-mail

I have Mac OS X and I accidentally locked the keychain and after a while I unlocked it again but now the mail app is not signing in with my Gmail account. Why is that? When I enter my password it is stuck in this state.

[image: Here is the screen shot of stuck situation.]

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Gmail account from your Mail and then add it again?

Comment: Yes and I got a solution by deleting the keychain of my mail and adding again

Comment: If you've successfully found an answer to your question, why wouldn't you post it as an answer? Otherwise your question will remain in unanswered category. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on how to proceed with self-answering.

Comment: For the question to be answered you need also [accept your answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: I've done it sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question which is as follows
I opened up the keychain preferences and deleted the mail keychain and typed the password for my mail then all set.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me after updating my password in a global environment, then this happened when i tried to update the login info for the mail app.

The Solution for me required deleting that entry in the accounts list and re-adding it.